# zurb foundation building block dashboard table odd td class

Tags: zurb-foundation

[Zurb -> Kits-> App Dashboard-> Dashboard Table](https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/dashboard-table.html)

has what appears to be a holdover class name from a previous project.

In the HTML code, there are several `<td class="listing-inquiry-status">` tags.

I assume these should be a different class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The class is not used in the (s)css so it should be fine to remove it.